# How can I set g.raphaeljs piechart orientation or starting point?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, graphael

By default g.raphaeljs piecharts show the largest value stretching from the top of the chart equally in both directions, with smaller values shown clockwise.

In the image below the largest value (1) starts at about 7 o'clock. I would like to show the largest value starting at 12 o'clock instead, how can that be done?

[image: Default behaviour]
[image: Target behaviour]

Comment: try playing with * g.pie.js* , right after that line `var mangle = angle - 360 * values[i] / total / 2;` , for example `mangle = mangle + 70;` of course you will need some smarter calculation...

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, that does the job. Now I'm hoping to figure out the calculation needed to make it work reliably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok , found it (**and it works 100%**)... over here: [Added opts.startFromFixedAngle, so the 1st pie-slice will start paint…](https://github.com/cederlof/g.raphael/commit/f532cd5d4233f8a4c02d07adcd39da1e5de81198)

[**Here is a working jsfiddle I just did : g raphael pie with starting angle set to 90**](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/tgyfC/)

Don't forget to use the new argument `startFromFixedAngle`

Here is the code...

Apply the following to your `g.pie.js`

replace

```
 angle = 0,
```

with

```
 angle = opts.startFromFixedAngle || 0,
```

remove

```
 var mangle = angle - 360 * values[i] / total / 2;
 if (!i) {
     angle = 90 - mangle;
```

add

```
 var mangle;
 if (opts.startFromFixedAngle)
     mangle = angle + 360 * values[i] / total / 2;
 else {
     mangle = angle - 360 * values[i] / total / 2;
     if (!i) {
         angle = 90 - mangle;
         mangle = angle - 360 * values[i] / total / 2;
     }
```

Comment: FYI, your linked Fiddle is now failing with a syntax error under Chrome 26.0.1410.65

Comment: +1 for a working fix, -90 degrees as a starting angle makes wonderful pac-man style piecharts.

Comment: since raw.github not working anymore, demo is not working. For a working one visit http://jsfiddle.net/tgyfC/14/

Answer (score 3):

The solution above is overly complicated and breaks any animation efforts dependent upon mangle (such as the one found here: [RaphaelJs Pie Chart Animation on Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363527/raphaeljs-pie-chart-animation-on-hover/8376775#8376775)).  A single line change is sufficient if all you want is a fixed start angle, but if you want to use an argument as above you would replace

```
     if (!i) {
       angle = 90 - mangle;
       mangle = angle - 360 * values[i] / total / 2;
     }
```

with

```
     if (!i) {
       if (opts.startFromFixedAngle) {
         angle = opts.startFromFixedAngle;
       } else {
         angle = 90 - mangle;
       }
       mangle = angle - 360 * values[i] / total / 2;
     }
```

In my case, I just wanted all pie charts to begin at the 90 degree mark so I simply removed "- mangle" from the code in the first block.

Comment: This will fail if you (for some reason) want to start your pie chart at degree 0. I ultimately went with this workaround, but added a check for a non-null opts.startFromFixedAngle.